# System.DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime not returning my local time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, dst

I'm getting a

> "The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time. For example, when
>   the clock is adjusted forward, any time in the period that is skipped
>   is invalid"

message when I try to convert a time to `UTC`.  The client that's experiencing the issue is in France, but the issue appears to have started when the US went to daylight savings time.  I see there's a spot in the code that's using Eastern Time Zone.  I'm thinking it must be somehow trying to use Eastern Standard time, somehow.

At any rate I tried mimicking their scenario by calling the same method after setting my locale to French/France and my timezone to Amsterdam, Berlin, etc.  My test code is doing:

```
DateTime eventDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
```

What doesn't make sense is that it's returning a date time as of Eastern Daylight Savings Time US, not the time that's being displayed by my system clock.  Is the BIOS clock set to EDT or something?  My intention was to pass eventDate to the method that seems to be working incorrectly for my French client.

Comment: Side note: `Now` is already `Kind=Local`, so your `ToLocalTime` call does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Can you use `DateTime.UtcNow` and skip the need for conversions except for presentation, i.e. work internally with just UTC DateTimes?

Comment: I added TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData(); and before my call to Now and it now returns the correct time.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is absolutely not possible.

You said you're getting the error:

> "The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time. For example, when the clock is adjusted forward, any time in the period that is skipped is invalid"

That can only happen when converting a local time to UTC - *not the other way around*.

Also, it can only occur when using the conversion methods on `TimeZoneInfo`.  For example, the following code will create an exception with that message:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 3, 9, 2, 30, 0);
DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz);
```

You might also think you'd get the same exception if your computer's time zone was set to "Eastern Standard Time" and you ran this code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 3, 9, 2, 30, 0);
DateTime utc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
```

However, this method will silently allow invalid input without throwing an exception.  It will just adjust forward an hour, as if you had passed 3:30 instead of 2:30.

Additionally, as others pointed out, `DateTime.Now` already is local and has `Local` kind.  So calling `ToLocalTime` on it won't do anything.  If you meant to call `ToUniversalTime`, then just use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.

You may also be interested in reading [the dst tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), and [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), which contain relevant details.

Comment: It's not the DateTime eventDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(); that's generating the error.  I'm just trying to create a datetime that's similar to what's being passed to the method that's creating the UTC date.  It's the method that's creating the UTC date that's throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I added TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData(); and before my call to Now and it now returns the correct time.